# Laravel - Lumen error al ejecutar despues de clonar el proyecto con git

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

Estaba haciendo una **API** con Lumen (un micro-framework de **Laravel**), tuve que borrarlo de mí PC por equis motivos, pero subí los últimos cambios al repositorio antes.

Entonces hice un `git clone` del proyecto y una vez bajado lo ejecute.

Entonces me metí en una de las rutas desde **Postman** (antes de borrar y clonar el proyecto funcionaba) y puse una de las rutas que tengo hechas, pero en la consola donde sé esta ejecutando **Lumen** me da este error :

> [Sun Dec 29 16:15:31 2019] 127.0.0.1:37922 Accepted [Sun Dec 29
>   16:15:31 2019] PHP Fatal error:  **Uncaught Error:** Class
>   'Laravel\Lumen\Bootstrap\LoadEnvironmentVariables' not found in
>   /home/asd/Documentos/proyectos/lumen_vue_sample/backend/test/bootstrap/app.php: Stack trace: #0 /home/asd/Documentos/proyectos/lumen_vue_sample/backend/test/public/index.php(14): require() #1 {main}   thrown in /home/asd/Documentos/proyectos/lumen_vue_sample/backend/test/bootstrap/app.php on line 5 [Sun Dec 29 16:15:31 2019] 127.0.0.1:37922 [500]: GET / - **Uncaught Error:** Class 'Laravel\Lumen\Bootstrap\LoadEnvironmentVariables' not found in /home/asd/Documentos/proyectos/lumen_vue_sample/backend/test/bootstrap/app.php:5 Stack trace: #0 /home/asd/Documentos/proyectos/lumen_vue_sample/backend/test/public/index.php(14): require() #1 {main}   thrown in /home/asd/Documentos/proyectos/lumen_vue_sample/backend/test/bootstrap/app.php on line 5 [Sun Dec 29 16:15:31 2019] 127.0.0.1:37922

No sé que pasos tengo que hacer después de clonar mi proyecto

Answer (score 1):

has revisado que no tengas archivos excluídos en el .gitignore que tengas que mover a mano?

has instalado las dependencias en la nueva ubicación?

si no ejecuta:

```
$ composer install
```

ya tiene la carpeta vendor en el repositorio?

intenta con:

```
composer update --no-scripts
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo tienes que copiar el archivo `.env.example` y cambiarle el nombre a `.env`, asegúrate de configurar las variables dentro.